# How to jest.mock an ES6 module import?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, es6-modules, tsx

I've moved a load of helper methods into a npm published library, but some of them are being mocked in the unit tests and I can't figure out how to mock the new imports.

Throughout my code I am able to successfully refactor .tsx files like so:

FROM:

```
import { doSomething } from "../../utils/stringUtils";
```

TO:

```
import { Utils } from "@mine/my-lovely-libary";
const { doSomething } = Utils;
```

But in the unit tests in spec.tsx I can't get the mocks to work:

```
jest.mock("../../utils/stringUtils", () => ({
    ...jest.requireActual("../../utils/stringUtils"),
    doSomething: (date: string) => date.toString(),
}));
```

I want to do something like this:

```
import { Utils } from "@mine/my-lovely-libary";
const { doSomething } = Utils;
jest.mock(doSomething);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you try to mock like this

```
jest.mock('@mine/my-lovely-libary', () => ({
    doSomething: () => doSomethingMock,
}));
```

here doSomething is a method from your npm library

doSomethingMock can be jest.fn() or something like this `const doSomethingMock = 'mockTestValue'`